# Hangfire with multiple Db and define queue name

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

I have a Net Core 6 Hangfire job project and i'm using two db, there is no problem with that. But two dashboards has the same queue name; "default"
I need to define each server to different queue names, but i cant. I need help with that.

Here is my code:

```
var hangfireUserStorageOptions = new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
    DisableGlobalLocks = true,
    SchemaName = "HangFireUser"
};

var hangfireSystemStorageOptions = new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
    DisableGlobalLocks = true,
    SchemaName = "HangFireSystem"
};

var hangfireUserStorage = new SqlServerStorage(_configuration.GetSection("HangfireSettings:HangfireConnection").Value, hangfireUserStorageOptions);
var hangfireSystemStorage = new SqlServerStorage(_configuration.GetSection("HangfireSettings:HangfireConnection").Value, hangfireSystemStorageOptions);

builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseSqlServerStorage(_configuration.GetSection("HangfireSettings:HangfireConnection").Value, hangfireSystemStorageOptions));

builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseSqlServerStorage(_configuration.GetSection("HangfireSettings:HangfireConnection").Value, hangfireUserStorageOptions));

builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(hangfireSystemStorage);   => i need to define queuename "Q1"
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(hangfireUserStorage);     => i need to define queuename "Q2"
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you should set the `QueueAttribute` on your job methods and then specify the desired queue names for those jobs.

```js
 [Queue("Q1")]
```

This way, you are explicitly setting the queue names for your jobs. When you enqueue jobs with different queue names, `Hangfire` will ensure that the jobs are processed by the servers that have been configured with the corresponding queue names.
When you enqueue a job, make sure to specify the corresponding queue name

Comment: Where should i set this attribute, on top of my service class ?

Comment: Hi @Osman Yalçınkaya You should apply this attribute directly to the methods in your service class that represent the jobs you want to run in different queues

Answer (score 1):

In order to  place a job into a different queue, we should use `QueueAttribute` class on your method. You can find that in `AddHangfireServer` which has the overload that allows us to set specific queue name. For example you should do that on `BackgroundJobServerOptions` if you want to use more queue for the background worker process.

```
 var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
    {
        Queues = new[] { "MyQ1", "Q2", "default" }
    };

app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

And your queue should like this

`[Queue("MyQ1")] public void YourQueueMethod() { }`

Finally, your `builder.Services.AddHangfireServer` should inlcude above queue configuratuion for calling two queue together within the same dashboard.

**Note:** Please [have a look at this official document](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html) if you need more details.

Comment: Yes but when we use "builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(hangfireSystemStorage)" this we can not give options anymore, thats our problem, hangfire doesnt let you pass these two params

Comment: No, `AddHangfireServer` has the overload where we can pass the queue option along with the param. I mean `services.AddHangfireServer(options =>
    {
        options.Queues = new[] { "Q1", "Q2", "default" };
    });`

Comment: All you need a bit modification. Could you please include your queue name along with the way so that it can be reproduced. I will take a look later on if that alright for you as well. Now going off line but I will investigate your issue.

Comment: I try this
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(options => { options.Queues = new[] { "Q1", "Q2", "default" }; }, hangfireUserStorage);
But gives error, i can not figured out how to modify this usage, i'll wait your help

Comment: I've found a solution, but it causes a new problem, check out this topic pls

Comment: Thanks for your response and glad to know your main issue has been resolved. However, as you have encoutered new issue so, it would be nice if you could post new question for that because, as per stackoverflow, one specific problem should be address under one question. I hope I have explained it clearly to you. Looking forward to your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Now I've found a solution.
Here it is;

```
var services = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

var userHangfireOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions{};
var systemHangfireOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions{};

builder.Services.AddHangfireServer((services, userHangfireOptions) =>
{
    userHangfireOptions.Queues = new[] { "app1_queue", "osman" };
    systemHangfireOptions.ServerName = "111";
}, hangfireUserStorage);

builder.Services.AddHangfireServer((services, systemHangfireOptions) =>
{
    systemHangfireOptions.Queues = new[] { "app1_queue", "ipek" };
    systemHangfireOptions.ServerName = "222";
}, hangfireSystemStorage);
```

But now we have a new problem.
This is my addjob code;

```
_recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(id, () => _hangfireService.ReccuringJob(new HangfireModel()), Cron.Minutely);
```

And i added queuename attribute. But this line of code just add jobs to first server. I need to add jobs with servername parameter, so i can add jobs to server which i want. This is the last problem.

Comment: ok so you are also generating the server name

Comment: yes i generate but when i add new job i can not choose the server. It always add just on server

Comment: ya I'll see that, but that enough for me that you are done with you problem ;)

Comment: thnaks very much :) as far as i understand that there is no solution to my problem, i read the whole internet, i need to make 2 seperate hangfire project i think.